# Getting Exception: java.sql.SQLException: Illegal operation on empty result set

Tags: java, mysql, sqlexception

Below is my code, basically i implement the sqlquery and i want that if the result is present in table than program continuoues with if condition otherwise if result is empty than the else condition will run.
I am getting exception when my the result of query is empty set, I don't know how to solve this query. After trying to debug many times I am to spot where this problem occurs. It occurs in if else statement.
If-else statment code:

```
while(!bool){
        try {
            rs = c.s.executeQuery("select * from employee where cnic = '"+s9+"'");
            rs.next();
            tempCnic = rs.getString("cnic");
            if(tempCnic.equals(s9)){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This CNIC Number is Already Registered");
                s9 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a correct CNIC Number:");
            } else if(tempCnic == null) {
                bool = true;
                c.s.executeUpdate("insert into employee values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"','"+s3+"','"+s4+"','"+s5+"','"+s6+"','"+s7+"','"+s8+"','"+s9+"','"+s10+"'");        
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee Added Successfully");
                new EmployeeMenu().setVisible(true);
                setVisible(false);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AddEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid Number");
        }
    }
```

The whole code:

```
JButton btnAdd = new JButton("Add");
btnAdd.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        conn c = new conn();
        String radio = null;
        
        if(male.isSelected()){ 
            radio = "Male";
        }
        else if(female.isSelected()){
            radio = "Female";
        }
     
    String s1 = (String)ID;
        String s2 = txtfirstname.getText();
        String s3 = txtlastname.getText();
        String s4 = txtage.getText();
        String s5 = radio;
        String s6 = (String)comboBox2.getSelectedItem();
        String s7 = txtsalary.getText();
        String s8 = txtphone.getText();
        String s9 = txtcnic.getText();    
        String s10 = txtemail.getText();
        
        ResultSet rs;
        String tempCnic;
        boolean bool = false;
        while(!bool){
            try {
                rs = c.s.executeQuery("select * from employee where cnic = '"+s9+"'");
                rs.next();
                tempCnic = rs.getString("cnic");
                if(tempCnic.equals(s9)){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "This CNIC Number is Already Registered");
                    s9 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a correct CNIC Number:");
                } else if(tempCnic == null) {
                    bool = true;
                    c.s.executeUpdate("insert into employee values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"','"+s3+"','"+s4+"','"+s5+"','"+s6+"','"+s7+"','"+s8+"','"+s9+"','"+s10+"'");        
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Employee Added Successfully");
                    new EmployeeMenu().setVisible(true);
                    setVisible(false);
                }
            } catch (SQLException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(AddEmployee.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            } catch(NumberFormatException ex){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please enter a valid Number");
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Please help me out and tell me what is the mistake I am making. Thanks!

Comment: `rs.next()` returns a boolean - Traditionally, the would go into either the `while()` or and `if()` - such as `while(rs.next()) {...}` or `if(rs.next()) {...}`.

Comment: @RandyCasburn You mean that I should remove `if(tempCnic.equals(s9))` with `if(rs.next()))` ??

Comment: Yes, with the next statement the assignment of `tempCnic`.